# Why am I getting: "Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'String?'"

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im working on an app with swift. Im loading a collection view with images from firebase.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "subPostCell", for: indexPath) as! SubPostCell

    cell.subPostImage.downloadImage(from: self.subposts[indexPath.row].pathToImage)

    return cell
}
```

It gives out an error in the `cell.subPostImage` line:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'String?'

This is my subpost object:

```
import Foundation

struct SubPost: Decodable {
    var pathToImage: [String]?
    var postID: String!
    var userID: String!

    init(pathToImage: [String]? = nil, postID: String? = nil, userID: String? = nil) {
        self.pathToImage = pathToImage
        self.postID = postID
        self.userID = userID
    }

}
```

This is my subpostscell code:

```
import UIKit

class SubPostCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var stepLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subPostImage: UIImageView!

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is pretty clear about whats going on, it says it expects a single String? to be passed while you are using are passing an Array of String?, that is your pathToImage. Most likely what you'll need to join the strings of your array into a single one.

Comment: Yeah, but each supbost has one main url that is sort of like the "thumbnail", the others are other things. I need to download the other urls, not the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code pathToImage has multiple urls.So you need to get specific url and download it,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "subPostCell", for: indexPath) as! SubPostCell
        if pathToImage.count > 0 {
            cell.subPostImage.downloadImage(from: self.subposts[indexPath.row].pathToImage[0])
        }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: How could i specify to download 3 of the 4 urls?

Comment: since its an array of strings that contains 4 strings

Comment: self.subposts[indexPath.row].pathToImage[0] chage the 0 to number you want to download (0-1st url , 1-2nd url , 2-3rd url, 3-4th url)